# Pass jquery variable to php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, php-5.3

I have a question I tried to pass a jquery variable to php but when I look in console I got an error:
SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list):`.append('<a href="'link+val.idno'">Edit</a>'`) and I don't understand where is the problem

```
var items=[];
var link = "<?php echo base_url()?>firm/editFirm/";
$.each(obj, function(i,val)
{
    $('#finalResult').text("Results");

    items.push($('<li/>').text
                            (
                                val.name_firm + "---" +
                                val.idno+"---" +
                                val.adresa+ "---" +
                                val.cont_banca+ "---" +
                                val.swit+ "---" +
                                val.banc_name+"---"
                            ).append("<a href='"link+val.idno"'>Edit</a>")
    );

});
```

Help me please.

Comment: How about trying to debug your code first on your own, then Googling a tad bit to find relevant problems and their solutions before copy pasting your problem here?

Comment: There are missing + in append(...) I guess. Between the strings and vars.

Answer (score 3):

You've missed the concatenation in the last bit:

`append("<a href='"link+val.idno"'>Edit</a>")`

Should be

`append("<a href='" + link + val.idno + "'>Edit</a>")`

Comment: Thx Tobias, stupid error

Answer (score 0):

I hope you aren't calling the php inside a .js file. I find it's cleaner to retrieve server-side variables using data-attributes inside DOM elements.

In the case of storing URLs for your use in Javascript, I'm really fond of the localize_script function of Wordpress, you just render the variables in a  tag in the header or footer via PHP and you have them all available in a nicely separated place.